# How to improve removing pandas df column names prefixes, based on imported nested json?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

### Situation

Importing a nested `json` into pandas I get the following example `df` with prefixed column names, what works as designed to avoid duplicated column headers.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4],
                   'product': ['a','b','c','d'],
                   'basic.productType':[1,2,3,4],
                   'basic.price':[100,200,300,400],
                   'location.city':['Bremen', 'Hamburg','Berlin','Karlsruhe'],
                   'location.city.zip':[1,2,3,4]
})
```

I also work with this `regex`solution to get rid of the *first level* prefixes (all characters including the seperator in this case a `.` and only for first occurrence):

```
df.columns = [re.sub('^[^.]+[.]','', name) for name in df.columns]
```

So columns look like this, after removing prefixes:

```
['id', 'product', 'productType', 'price', 'city', 'city.zip']
```

### Question

Is there any solution you could suggest to improve my and that is generic(no use of lists of prefixs)? Cause I am not that familiar with `regex` and maybe there are simpler solutions, also non `regex` too.

Comment: Seems like a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question to me. What's your actual problem if it works?

Comment: @Wolf Thanks for introducing code review, does not know about it - Problem is my limited regex knowledge in the moment and I like to understand the things I am doing, so when ever I can use "speaking code" I would go this way. So solution based on "basic methods" of jezral fixed this issue very well, cause I am more familiar with that.

Comment: for me your `^[^.]+[.]` was "speaking code" -- trust me: it helps a lot to get used to regex :)

Comment: I will do :) But my level doesn't seem even close to yours so it was really hard to get it to work. Learned a lot and think other newcomer would also appreciate such a more "speaking" solution. Anyway - regex here I come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with split, but in general data is possible duplicated columns names, so if select one column like `df['col']` get all columns `col`:

EDIT: You can split values with `.` in [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.where.html)

```
df.columns = df.columns.where(~df.columns.str.contains('\.'), 
                               df.columns.str.split('.', n=1).str[1])
print (df)
   id product  productType  price       city  city.zip
0   1       a            1    100     Bremen         1
1   2       b            2    200    Hamburg         2
2   3       c            3    300     Berlin         3
3   4       d            4    400  Karlsruhe         4
```

Or:

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('.', 1)[1] if '.' in x else x)
```

Alternative of your solution with [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('^[^.]+[.]','')
```

Comment: Very smart solution, and thanks for your change - It was my mistake, had thought the regex implied that there are also deeper nestings. have improved the question and examples

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('.', -1)[-1] if '.' in x else x)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of your code.